# AdvancedWebView loading html from phone storage issue

Tags: android, android-webview

Hi i am using  compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0' for display html5, my target file is stored in my phone storage path is "file:///storage/sdcard0/DcLms/Conjunction/index.html". when I am working with normal android WebView no issues. But trying with above mentioned library i got Webpage not available issue.

```
 String targetPath = "file:///storage/sdcard0/DcLms/Conjunction/index.html";
 AdvancedWebView webView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 webView.loadUrl(targetPath);

 WebView basicView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.basicView);
 webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

 basicView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 basicView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 basicView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 basicView.loadUrl(targetPath);
 basicView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Comment: thanks for you response. but i have one doubt. loadData() having three parameters first one is our url, rest of two(String mimeType, String encoding) how can I set?

Comment: loadData() not working

Answer (score 1):

First of all `AdvancedWebView` configures all settings automatically on it's instantiating. Take a look on the sources [here](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/blob/master/Source/library/src/main/java/im/delight/android/webview/AdvancedWebView.java).

And the problem is that by default `AdvancedWebView` dissallow access using `file://` scheme:

```
    ...
    final WebSettings webSettings = getSettings();
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
    setAllowAccessFromFileUrls(webSettings, false);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    ...
```

So after creation of `AdvancedWebView` you need to add following lines:

```
 AdvancedWebView webView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
 }
```

**NOTE**: `AdvancedWebView` just subclassing `WebView` so it will not make any difference - the only difference that it configurating settings for you and handle some of the events.